# Type casting struct in C++

Tags: c++

In C++ I am facing some difficulties!
I want to know what will be c++ equivalent of these c statement?

```
struct stat sb; // this is struct, will be same in c++

printf("I-NODE NUMBER: %ld\n", (long) sb.st_ino); // this is C statement

// c++ statement of above statement

cout<<" Inode number: "<< (long) sb.st_ino; // is this the correct way?

// or this one

cout<<" Inode number: "<< (long) (long) sb.st_ino; // is this the correct way?
```

Comment: better to use `static_cast` instead. (i.e., `static_cast<long>(sb.st_ino)`).

Comment: Yes. What's the problem?

Comment: Why cast it twice? Surely once is enough.

Comment: Thankyou guys, also, will this work too? static_cast<string> sb.st_rdev;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although c-style casts will work in `c++` it is considered better style to use `C++` style casts. That is use `static_cast` in the cases you list. Like so:

```
cout<<" Inode number: "<< static_cast<long>(sb.st_ino);
```

Also in the last example there is no sense in casting an expression twice to the same type. If what you try to write is a cast to `long long` use:

```
cout<<" Inode number: "<< static_cast<long long>(sb.st_ino);
```

Also look up dynamic_cast, const_cast, reinterpret_cast(last two should be avoided whenever possible).

Comment: Of course, you don't need a cast here at all. It's only needed in C because `printf` isn't type-safe, and requires the argument type to match the format specifier.

Comment: @MikeSeymour good point. Casting will only be needed in less common cases where for instance we want to print the character that has a fixed ASCII code.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you'd probably just do the following. The cast isn't necessary at all.

```
std::cout << " Inode number: " << sb.st_ino;
```